# How do you set an epigraph attribution in poemscol?

Tags: epigraphs

I'm using poemscol to set a 1,500+ page edition of a poet's work. The \epigraph{} command does a great job of rendering epigraphs that appear between a poem's title and the start of its first stanza. However, I need to be able to add an attribution to these epigraphs. How can I do that in poemscol?

Comment: I don't understand your problem. The `epigraph` package allows attrributions and can be placed wherever you want in your document. Please provide an MWE (from `\documentclass ... to \end{document}` that shows your problem.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436/170958) It'd be helpful if you could add an [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/170958) to your question. However, may I still ask (though I don't know barely anything about `poemscol`) if simply adding another `\attribution{}` under the `\epigraph{}` wouldn't work?

Comment: Thanks @PeterWilson. I think the confusion here may be because poemscol provides its own \epigraph{} command:

\newcommand{\epigraph}[1]{\nopagebreak\afterpoemtitleskip\testforcenterepigraph%
\begin{epigraphquote}%
 \emph{#1}\end{epigraphquote}\afterpoemtitleskip\nopagebreak}

I get the sense that this doesn't allow for attributions, and that my solution will have to be to write a custom command that takes two arguments, one for the epigraph and another for the attribution, as the \epigraph{} command does in the \epigraph{} package.

Comment: @steve thanks to you, too; the comment above wouldn't let me @ in more than one user!

Comment: It looks like from the manual that `\epigraph{}` followed by `\attribution{}` is the intended usage, cf @steve's comment. However, you can put further text and formatting into the argument to `\epigraph{}`, even \\ newline etc: `\epigraph{xxx \\ \normalsize\normalfont xxx xxx xxx}`.

Comment: @Cicada ah, I interpreted \attribution{} as to be used to creating attributions to a poem itself: i.e., noting the author of the poem. Have I missed something in the manual? What are you reading that suggests to you that this is the intended usage of \attribution{}?

Comment: @Jim Three things: a presumption that `\attribution` is not a term of art (so didn't google its meaning); command names are arbitrary labels for typesetting instructions (so I approached `\attribution{}` as if it were `\x{}` where x = peach, pear, persimmon, etc) - in any case, commands can be re-defined, and/or accept other formatting commands as input); and the volume versions on p 69 of the manual (c 21) had this: `\volumeepigraph{There is in short no absolute time standard.}
\volumeattribution{{\em Van Nostrand's Scientific Encyclopedia,\/}\\
Fifth Edition, p. 2203}` epi+attr pairing,

Comment: @Cicada thank you! I'd interpreted \attribution differently, but according to John Burt's answer below your interpretation is correct. I think I must have seen an incorrect use of \attribution somewhere (i.e. one that was intended to create an attribution to a poem).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I intended \attribution to handle the attributions for epigraphs to poems. I intended \volumeattribution to handle the attributions for epigraphs on volume title pages. I didn't write a command for attributing poems to their authors, but it would be easy to do so. I suggest the code below, which will line up the attribution with the left margin of the verse block, even when the verse block is centered on the longest line:

\newlength{\poemattributionindent}
\setlength{\poemattributionindent}{\leftmargin}
\newcommand{\variablepoemattributionindent}{
\setlength{\poemattributionindent}{\linewidth}
\addtolength{\poemattributionindent}{-\versewidth}
\addtolength{\poemattributionindent}{-.5\poemattributionindent}}
\newcommand{\poemattribution}[1]{\iflastpoemcentered\variablepoemattributionindent
\else\setlength{\poemattributionindent}{\leftmargin}
\fi
\bigskip\begin{raggedleft}\hspace{\poemattributionindent}#1\end{raggedleft}\bigskip}

Comment: Thank you for this clarification, John, I'll use \attribution! And thank you, more generally, for poemscol, it's making our typesetting and editing work so much more straightforward.

Comment: I've just uploaded a new version to CTAN which includes the new \poemattribution command (among some other new things). (ps. Whose poems are you editing? I've been working with the editor of an edition of the complete poems of Jose Maria Heredia, whose questions have helped me improve poemscol immensely.)